# Struggling to enable SSLv2Hello in Apache CXF, Java 8, No Spring

Tags: ssl, java-8, cxf

This is going to seem backwards, but I'm developing a web server specifically to interface with a third party client.  This third party client only supports SSLv3, TLSv1.0, or TLSv1.1.

I'm also seeing the following errors on my side when they try to connect:

```
SSLHandshakeException: SSLv2Hello is not enabled
```

I assume that means they also require SSLv2Hello to be enabled.  It's clearly not for me, although it seems to be available.

```
2019-06-13 15:06:38.831:DBUG:oejus.SslContextFactory:MyProgram: Selected Protocols [TLSv1.1, TLSv1] of [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, SSLv3, SSLv2Hello]
2019-06-13 15:06:38.831:DBUG:oejus.SslContextFactory:MyProgram: Selected Ciphers   [TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV] of [TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
```

Not sure if this is a red herring, but if I try to do the following to SSLContext.getInstances, the TLSv1.1 call works fine, the SSLv2Hello throws a NoSuchAlgorithmException.

```
SSLContext.getInstance( "TLSv1.1" )
SSLContext.getInstance( "SSLv2Hello" )
```

The code I'm running to spin this thing up is still a mess since I'm prototyping, but it's below to get the gist of what I'm doing.

```
        final String url = "https://myurl.com:443/Notices";

        TLSServerParameters params = new TLSServerParameters();

        List<String> certFilePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        certFilePaths.add( "COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt" );
        certFilePaths.add( "AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt" );
        certFilePaths.add( "COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt" );
        certFilePaths.add( "MyCert.crt" );

        Utility.loadCertsToServerParams( certFilePaths, "SSL_Export.pfx", "/tmp/tmp.jks", "password", params ); //uses the ssl password as the temporary keystore password as well

        JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory serverEngineFactory = new JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory();
        serverEngineFactory.setTLSServerParametersForPort( 443, params );

        Consumer implementor = new Consumer();
        JaxWsServerFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
        factory.setServiceClass( Consumer.class );
        factory.setAddress( url );
        factory.setServiceBean( implementor );

        Map<String, Object> properties = Maps.newHashMap();
        properties.put( "mtom-enabled", "false" );
        factory.setProperties( properties );

        final Map<String, Object> inProps = Utility.getWsSecurityPropertiesForSSL( "/tmp/tmp.jks", "SSL_Export.pfx", "password", "SSL_Export" );

        WSS4JInInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JInInterceptor( inProps );
        factory.getInInterceptors().add( wssOut );

        ServerImpl server = ( ServerImpl ) factory.create();

        server.start();



public static TrustManager[] loadCertsToServerParams( List<String> serverCertFilePaths, String sslTlsKeyPairPath, String tempPathForCertFileKeystore, String sslTslKeyPairPassword, TLSServerParameters params ) throws Exception
{
    char[] sslTslKeyPairPasswordCharArray = sslTslKeyPairPassword.toCharArray();

    //clear out the keystore, we create a new one every time
    if( Files.exists( Paths.get( tempPathForCertFileKeystore ) ) )
        Files.delete( Paths.get( tempPathForCertFileKeystore ) );

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance( "PKCS12" );

    ks.load( new FileInputStream( sslTlsKeyPairPath ), sslTslKeyPairPasswordCharArray );

    // Store away the newly created keystore.
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( tempPathForCertFileKeystore );
    ks.store( fos, sslTslKeyPairPasswordCharArray );
    fos.close();

    for( String certFilePath : serverCertFilePaths )
        AddCertToKeystore( ks, sslTslKeyPairPasswordCharArray, tempPathForCertFileKeystore, certFilePath, new File( certFilePath ).getName().replace( '.', '_' ) );

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance( TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm() );
    tmf.init( ks );

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance( KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm() );
    kmf.init( ks, sslTslKeyPairPasswordCharArray );

    SSLContext tls1_1Context = SSLContext.getInstance( "TLSv1.1" );
    tls1_1Context.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom() );
    SSLContext.setDefault( tls1_1Context );

    SSLContext v2Hello = SSLContext.getInstance( "SSL" );
    v2Hello.init( kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom() );

    params.setTrustManagers( tmf.getTrustManagers() );
    params.setKeyManagers( kmf.getKeyManagers() );
    params.setSecureSocketProtocol( "SSL" );
    final List<String> additionalProtocols = new ArrayList<>();
    additionalProtocols.add( "SSLv2Hello" );
    additionalProtocols.add( "SSLv3" );
    additionalProtocols.add( "TLSv1" );
    additionalProtocols.add( "TLSv1.1" );
    additionalProtocols.add( "TLSv1.2" );
    params.setIncludeProtocols( additionalProtocols );
    params.setExcludeProtocols( null );
    final FiltersType cipherFilter = new FiltersType();
    cipherFilter.getInclude().add( ".*NULL.*" );
    cipherFilter.getInclude().add( ".*anon.*" );
    cipherFilter.getInclude().add( ".*EXPORT.*" );
    cipherFilter.getInclude().add( ".*DES.*" );
    cipherFilter.getInclude().add( ".*MD5" );
    cipherFilter.getInclude().add( ".*CBC.*" );
    cipherFilter.getInclude().add( ".*RC4.*" );
    cipherFilter.getInclude().add( ".*_.*" );
    cipherFilter.getInclude().add( ".*AES.*" );
    cipherFilter.getInclude().add( ".*_SHA" );
    cipherFilter.getExclude().add( "" );
    params.setCipherSuitesFilter( cipherFilter );
    final List<String> cipherSuites = new ArrayList<>();
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" );
    cipherSuites.add( "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV" );
    params.setCipherSuites( cipherSuites );

    return tmf.getTrustManagers();
}
```

I'm explicitly setting SSLv2Hello as an additional protocol as suggested in this Jetty github issue, what am I missing to get SSLv2Hello enabled?

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/866

Comment: Update:  If I specify the same settings against an SSLContextFactory (protocols and cipher suites) and then create a new SSLEngine from that factory, the command line output indicates SSLv2Hello is enabled.  It seems there is something I'm missing about the CXF params to get into the same state versus some java security setting or anything else bricking SSLv2Hello on my configuration.

Comment: CXF version 3.24, jetty 9.4.8.v20171121.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a CXF bug.  When JettyHTTPServer engine runs createSSLContext, it never calls setIncludeProtocols on the protocols included as part of TlsServerParameters.  If I create my own SslContextFactory and specify them, then that factory includes SSLv2Hello.  I don't see a way to use my factory, though.  The JettyHTTPServerEngine seems to new up it's own with no option otherwise.  Maybe there is an alternate way to specify include parameters that I'm not familiar with?  Seems counter to the documentation here https://cxf.apache.org/docs/tls-configuration.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a CXF bug.  If I create my own JettyHTTPServerEngine based on a copy of the source and add the following line:

```
scf.setIncludeProtocols( "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2", "SSLv2Hello" );
```

to this method:

```
protected SSLContext createSSLContext( SslContextFactory scf) throws Exception
```

then the behavior is as I would expect, where the debug output indicates those protocols are now supported, and the connection succeeds.

> Selected Protocols [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, SSLv2Hello] of [TLSv1.3,
>   TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1, SSLv3, SSLv2Hello]

I do not see the setIncludeProtocols function anywhere in the original JettyHTTPServerEngine code, either in my 3.2.4 version or on master in GitHub, so I cannot imagine how this works or was supposed to work.

Comment: @ColmOhEigeartaigh Can you confirm I'm not missing something here if you get a chance?